# Text classification and most informative features

Tags: python, nlp

I'm trying to do some text classification and understand which are the most informative feature the model uses.

I get the Accuracy of the model but when it comes to understand the feature_names it's shows and empty row ''
(accuracy: 0.38405797101449274
Top 10 features used to predict:
Class 1 best:
(0.006863555955628847, '')
Class 2 best:
(0.006863555955628847, '')

If i call the feature_names by itself it shows an empty result but i dont understand where in the function i've made the mistake.

Those are the Def created for cleaning

```
STOPLIST = stopwords.words('italian')
SYMBOLS = " ".join(string.punctuation).split(" ") + ["-", "...", "”", "”"]
class CleanTextTransformer(TransformerMixin):
    def transform(self, X, **transform_params):
        return [cleanText(text) for text in X]
    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self
    def get_params(self, deep=True):
        return {}
    
def cleanText(text):
    text = text.strip().replace("\n", " ").replace("\r", " ")
    text = text.lower()
    return text
```

Those are the Def created for tokenizing

```
def tokenizeText(sample):
    tokens = parser(sample)
    lemmas = []
    for tok in tokens:
        lemmas.append(tok.lemma_.lower().strip() if tok.lemma_ != "-PRON-" else tok.lower_)
    tokens = lemmas
    tokens = [tok for tok in tokens if tok not in STOPLIST]
    tokens = [tok for tok in tokens if tok not in SYMBOLS]
    return tokens
```

and the one for the Most Informative features

```
def printNMostInformative(vectorizer, clf, N):
    feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
    coefs_with_fns = sorted(zip(clf.coef_[0], feature_names))
    topClass1 = coefs_with_fns[:N]
    topClass2 = coefs_with_fns[:-(N + 1):-1]
    print("Class 1 best: ")
    for feat in topClass1:
        print(feat)
    print("Class 2 best: ")
    for feat in topClass2:
        print(feat)
```

Then the classic Pipeline with the LinearSVC model (i wanted to try more but i'm trying to understand which one perform better).

```
# data
train1 = train['Column Interested'].tolist()
labelsTrain1 = train['Column Interested'].tolist()
test1 = test['Column Interested'].tolist()
labelsTest1 = test['Column Interested'].tolist()

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenizeText, ngram_range=(1,1))
clf = LinearSVC()

pipe = Pipeline([('cleanText', CleanTextTransformer()), ('vectorizer', vectorizer), ('clf', clf)])



# train
pipe.fit(train1, labelsTrain1)

# test
preds = pipe.predict(test1)
print("accuracy:", accuracy_score(labelsTest1, preds))
print("Top 10 features used to predict: ")

printNMostInformative(vectorizer, clf, 10)
```

For more usability there is a very similar use of this "NMostinformative on this tutorial which I adapted to my data
https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-for-text-classification-using-spacy-in-python-b276b4051a49

Comment: A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful for others to understand your problem better.

Comment: I hope I added enough example to be reproducible